# Modifications in Performance Analytics charts

Tags: r, xts, zoo, performanceanalytics

I am visualising various financial series in R. I am using Performance Analytics package in R for this. Is there any way to do modifications in charts created by this package like changing the title of the chart, axis titles etc.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
data<-managers
charts.PerformanceSummary(data$HAM1)
```

Comment: see the arguments of function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

charts.PerformanceSummary is a flexible function. You can do modifications with the help of different arguments. For example for changing the title just specify main argument. If you want interactive charts you can specify plot.engine argument.

```
charts.PerformanceSummary(data$HAM1,main="your_title")
charts.PerformanceSummary(data$HAM1,plot.engine="plotly")
```